# Ubuntu 15.04 second monitor is blank with blinking LED

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have a VisionTek Radeon card with 3 DVI outputs. I've connected one to a DVI monitor and the second to a VGA monitor using an adapter. Both show up in settings|display and Catalyst, but the VGA one is always blank and has a blinking LED.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
      DFP1 connected 1280x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
         1280x768      59.81*+
         1920x1080     60.00 +
         1680x1050     60.00  
         1400x1050     60.00  
         1600x900      60.00  
         1360x1024     60.00  
         1280x1024     60.02  
         1440x900      59.89  
         1280x960      60.02  
         1280x800      59.81  
         1152x864      60.00    75.00  
         1280x720      59.81  
         1024x768      70.07    60.00  
         800x600       60.32    56.25  
         640x480       67.00    59.94  
      DFP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
      DFP3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
         1920x1080     60.00*+
         1680x1050     59.95  
         1400x1050     59.95  
         1600x900      59.95  
         1360x1024     59.95  
         1280x1024     60.02  
         1440x900      59.89  
         1280x960      60.02  
         1280x800      59.81  
         1152x864      60.00    75.00  
         1280x768      59.81  
         1280x720      59.86  
         1024x768      70.07    60.00  
         800x600       60.32    56.25  
         640x480       66.61    59.94
```

Any ideas on what I've got configured wrong?

Comment: It is very unlikely that a VGA monitor will support 3200x1080. Are the screens mirrored, or do the monitors extend the desktop? Try reducing the display temporarily to a typical VGA setting, like 1280x1024, and see if the VGA monitor handles it.

Comment: A bit obvious question, but does the monitor with the VGA/DB15 input work on other systems? Just to rule out potential monitor and cable problems.  Does the card output a VGA signal or is it pure digital DVI?

Comment: fair question, yes it works fine on other vga systems.

Comment: @AFH i tried this, no luck.  Same deal, catalyst sees it but the monitor is black and the led just blinks.

Comment: To expand on @Hennes' query, what did you connect to the other system: the VGA cable, or the cable with the DVI adapter? And are you sure that both systems have the same DVI (both DVI-D or both DVI-A/DVI-I)? Implicit in Hennes' comment was that a passive DVI to VGA adapter works only if the DVI is DVI-A or DVI-I.

Comment: i now realize what i think the problem is.  the old system had a DVI-A splitter which could connect to VGA but the new system only has a DVI-I.  So i think the issue is that the old monitors cannot read the new video card signals no matter what b/c the new video card only outputs digital whereas the old video card output both digital and analog (forgive me if i'm bastardizing the vocabulary). i've ordered a new monitor that takes DVI in, i'll let you know if this solves the problem.   thanks for your help on this so far.